# Prevent variable value from resetting on refresh in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I made a simple `click` event in javascript, when button clicked variabel `i` adds value with `150`. Then I send it to firebase. But when I refresh my index page and click button again the value restart at `0` again in Firebase.

What code do I need to change?

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://***.firebaseIO.com');
var i = 0;

$('.btn').click(function() {
   i = i + 150;
   myDataRef.set({value: i});
});

$('.progress-bar').css({ 'width' : i});

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: If you want to have it persistent on reload, you either need to retrieve that value form the server (if it is stored there)  or save it in `localStorage` or in a `cookie`

Comment: How do I retrieve it from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently initialize `i` to 0 when the page loads.

You should also get the value from Firebase, which you can do with:

```
myDataRef.child('value').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    i = snapshot.val();
});
```

If you combine that with the existing code and clean it up a bit, it becomes:

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://***.firebaseIO.com');

var i = 0;
$('.progress-bar').css({ 'width' : i});  

myDataRef.child('value').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    i = snapshot.val();
    $('.progress-bar').css({ 'width' : i});
});

$('.btn').click(function() {
   myDataRef.set({value: i + 150});
});

$(document).ready(main);
```

Note that the initial snippet I gave uses `once('value'`, while here we use `on('value'`. This means the latest code will actually keep listening for updated values from Firebase, which is normally what you want.

So the initial flow here is:

1. You initialize `i` to 0 and draw the progress bar
2. You start listening for values from Firebase
3. You start listening for `click` events
4. At some point a new value arrives from Firebase, which
5. Updates `i` and the progress bar

Then when the user clicks the button:

- You update the value in Firebase, which triggers steps 4 and 5 from above

Comment: Aha thats how you retriev it from Firebase! Thank you for helping me!

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that you're not just *retrieving* the value from Firebase once, you're *synchronizing* is continuously. So if another visitor to the page clicks the button, your progress bar will also update.

Comment: Is it hard to bind the value to a user logged in to Facebook, using Firebase user Authentication?

Comment: Firebase's documentation has a good section on how they propose you store user data: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing. What I find important about that is the realization that the `users` node is a regular Firebase node like any other. So you can add whatever data you want to it, including your `value` (you might want to pick a more meaningful name though). Just read the documentation and try to get it working. If you run into problems, open a new question with the minimal code to reproduce your question.

Answer (score 0):

The variable restarts from `0` because you reload your page code so the initialization of `i = 0` executes again.

To avoid this you can:

- Extract `i` to another file that don't get reloaded, using it like a variable external to this file scope.
- Read the value from your current Firebase value

Comment: How do I extract i to another file that don't get reloaded, using it like a variable external to this file scope.(thank you for your answer:))

Comment: This option is probably the worse and will depend on your project layout. 
If your code has a master page that won't get reloaded when you refresh the code inside the page with the button you can load a .js file in this master page when you define a global variable to use.

Usually this is not a good approach on javascript and I think you should try to read your current data from Firebase

Comment: okey, you have any suggestion how to read my current data from Firebase?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no experience with firebase, but I assume that if you can SET data to it you should also be able to GET it. I'd try something like var i = myDataRef.get({value});